# Paste files with extended delimiter in bash

Tags: bash, paste

Good day people!

Today, I was wondering how to paste several files with this delimiter: `,,`.

When I use like:

```
paste -d',,' ...
```

The output only introduce one `,`

I need double comma for better handling csv files, Thanks in advance for any clue

Comment: Unfortunately, `paste` assumes that there's just a single delimiter character between each field, it doesn't work when fields are delimited by more than one character.

Comment: When you give multiple characters to the `-d` option, it uses the first character as the delimiter after the first field, the second character after the second field, and so on.

Comment: mmm, good point. maybe, is some way to work around?

Comment: Actually, I misread the man page. Now I see that `-d` is for specifying the output format, not input.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you can identify a character which is not used in the file, you can do this in two steps.

```
paste -d '~' file1 file2 | sed 's/~/,,/'
```

Obviously, if the tilde already exists in your data, use a different delimiter. A control character could be a fairly safe bet, at the expense of being slightly pesky to manipulate. (In Bash, you can use e.g. `$'\001'` to produce a ctrl-A, etc.)

Answer (score 4):

This works:

```
paste -d, file1 /dev/null file2
```

The documentation says:

> If end-of-file is reached on an input file
>        while other input files still contain data, the file is treated as if it were an endless source of empty lines.

Since `/dev/null` returns EOF immediately, it will simply be an endless source of blank lines. These will be inserted as an empty field between the contents of the two real files.

Answer (score 2):

An `awk` command can also do the job with `OFS=',,'`:

```sh
awk -v OFS=',,' 'NR==FNR{a[FNR]=$0; next} {print a[FNR], $0}' file1 file2
```